# How to redirect to a specific route from within ExpressJS API code?

Tags: node.js, angular, express, routes

I want to be able to redirect my MEAN app to the Login page whenever there is no valid login.

I have a component, which on `ngOninit()` calls an API route.

The API route looks like:

```
router.get("/route", isLoggedIn, (req, res) => {
});
```

Where `isLoggedIn` is:

```
function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    return next();
  } else {
    console.log("Not Logged in");
    res.redirect("http://localhost:3000/login");
  }
}
```

When `res.redirect("http://localhost:3000/login")` is executed, it throws an error in the console: "Template parse error". I guess this has something to do with the component which called the API waiting for the response from the API.

What's the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handle it in your MEAN app, redirect the user to login page from angular and from API return a JSON response.

```
res.status(401).json({error: "Unauthorized Access"});
```

In you angular side, in the response of this API call check if you get this error then redirect user to login page. you could do this by using angular service. `$location`

```
$location.url('/login');
```

For generic solution to check authentication on every route you should use  `http interceptor`. Please have look at following stackoverflow question:

> [AngularJs route authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32679348/angularjs-route-authentication)

Comment: So  I should do this for all the calls? Is there some generic way to do it? Rather than writing this check in all the calls?

Comment: @NimishDavidMathew I have updated my answer please have a look I hope it helps .

Comment: Yes. Thank you!

Comment: @NimishDavidMathew Welcome!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using angular then you need to manage to route on the angular side. You can send some sort of HTTP code or response to tell your angular app that request is unauthorized.

You can write general wrapper that send a request to your node server and check for the error. You can write general function according to the logic and library you are using but that would be something like this.

```
function makeRequest(url,..., callback) {
  request(...).then(response => {
    if(resp.status === 401) $location.url('/login');
    else callback(resp.data)
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping!